# Class 'kartik\base\InputWidget' not found

Tags: yii2-advanced-app, yii-widgets, kartik-v

In my Yii2 apps I add extension select2, since composer not successfully downloaded all the needed librarys. So I do it manually but I have still have error. Any help is BIG THANKS.

[Here is my error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDOMP.png)

Comment: hi guys... help.

Comment: Please edit your question so to incorporate your code and the error message as text. That would make your question more easy to find and possibly attract more users able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think since you did it manually you

- forgot to add this file: [input widget file](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-krajee-base/blob/master/InputWidget.php)
- or did not specify proper path to it.
  Check these and come back if any issues prevail.And always try to use composer as it's better to solve composer errors than finding what is missing after doing the entire set up.Isn't it? ;)